# how to find range inside checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a column named ***weight*** in my table **accounts**. i need to fetch the values from this column like,

when the user clicks weight from 40 - 100, It need to display all the persons with weight in between 40 and 100.

This is my html code,

```
<div class="float-right span35">
    <form class="list-wrapper search-form" method="get" action="{{CONFIG_SITE_URL}}/index.php">
        <div class="list-header">
            Talent Search
        </div>
                <h4 style="margin-left: 10px; color: gray;">Weight</h4>
                <fieldset id="weight">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="weight" value="1" {{WEIGHT_1}}/>Below 40<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="weight" value="2" {{WEIGHT_2}}/>40-70<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="weight" value="3" {{WEIGHT_3}}/>70-100<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="weight" value="4" {{WEIGHT_4}}/>Above 100<br>
                </fieldset>
                <br/>
                <input style="margin-left: 10px" type="submit" name="submit" value="search"/><br><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="tab1" value="search">
        </form>
</div>
```

This is my php code,

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){


    $weight = ($_GET['weight'])? $escapeObj->stringEscape($_GET['weight']): NULL;

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM `".DB_ACCOUNTS."` WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL ";

    if(is_numeric($weight) && $weight != NULL){
        $sql .= "AND `weight` IN (".$weight.")"; 
        $is_weight = true;
    }

    $sql .= " ORDER BY `id` ASC";

    }
    if($is_weight){
        $themeData['weight_'.$weight] = 'checked';
    }

    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
            while($fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $get[] = $fetch['id'];
            }

            $i = 0;
            $listResults = '';

            $themeData['page_title'] = "Advanced Search - ".$lang['search_result_header_label']; 
            foreach($get as $row){
                $timelineObj = new \SocialKit\User();
                $timelineObj->setId($row);
                $timeline = $timelineObj->getRows();

                $themeData['list_search_id'] = $timeline['id'];
                $themeData['list_search_url']   = $timeline['url'];
                $themeData['list_search_username'] = $timeline['username'];
                $themeData['list_search_name'] = $timeline['name'];
                $themeData['list_search_thumbnail_url'] = $timeline['thumbnail_url'];

                $themeData['list_search_button'] = $timelineObj->getFollowButton();

                $listResults .= \SocialKit\UI::view('search/list-each');
                $i++;
            }
            $themeData['list_search_results'] = $listResults; 

    }

}
```

This code is almost working for an single weight from table. But I need to create a range in between the checkbox values as i mentioned in the code. Do i need to update the code.

Comment: if you are going to add a range you will need to make changes  in your query and add something like "where weight >=min   && weight <= max"

Comment: As im a fresher and new to php and mysql I dont know how to clearly do it. can u help me there to find. @bdalina .

Comment: what value is being passed to php? this 1,2,3,4? each has min and max 1=40 to 100?

Comment: integer values stored in database table is passed

Comment: Don't build SQL queries by string concatenation.  That way SQL injection attacks lie.

Answer (score 0):

In php code change

```
if(is_numeric($weight) && $weight != NULL){
    $sql .= "AND `weight` IN (".$weight.")"; 
    $is_weight = true;
}
```

To

```
if(is_numeric($weight) && $weight != NULL){
    if($weight==1){
        $sql .= "AND weight<40";
    }
    if($weight==2){
        $sql .= "AND weight>=40 AND weight <=70";
    }
    if($weight==3){
        $sql .= "AND weight>70 AND weight <=100";
    }
    if($weight==4){
        $sql .= "AND weight>100";
    }
    $is_weight = true;
}
```

Also, I **recommend using radio instead of check box** as with check boxes, if you select more than one weight options one value will be lost.

Comment: your right he must use radio, and add another option for All 1,2,3,4, All means 0 -100 above etc..

Comment: _/?weight=weight+>70+and+weight+<%3D100&submit=search_  my url become like this but no results are viewing

Comment: Ignore HTML recommendations given before. update PHP code as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this works, so you won't make big changes in your code

Use radion button

```
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="0" {{WEIGHT_1}}/>Below 40<br>
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="1" {{WEIGHT_2}}/>40-70<br>
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="2" {{WEIGHT_3}}/>70-100<br>
<input type="radio" name="weight" value="3" {{WEIGHT_4}}/>Above 100<br>
```

You can add a variable array in php

```
$arrayWeight = ["`weight` >= 0 && `weight` <=40", 
                "`weight` >= 40 && `weight` <=70", 
                "`weight` >=70 && `weight` <=100",
                "`weight` >= 100"];

//  $arrayWeight[$weight] = $arrayWeight[1];
//  $arrayWeight[1] = 'weight' >= 0 && 'weight' <=40    a string
```

at this line  add do this

```
if(is_numeric($weight) && $weight != NULL)
    {
        $sql .= "AND ".$arrayWeight[$weight].")";  //sample $arrayWeight[1] = 'weight' >= 0 && 'weight' <=40

        //" SELECT id FROM `".DB_ACCOUNTS."` WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL AND 'weight' >= 0 && 'weight' <=40

        $is_weight = true;
    }
```

be care-full with quotes

Comment: where i need to put this $arrayWeight = ["",   //why empty means it will query all regardless of the weight
                "'weight' >= 0 && 'weight' <=40", 
                "'weight' >= 40 && 'weight' <=70", 
                "'weight' >=70 && 'weight' <=100",
                "'weight' >= 100",];

//  $arrayWeight[$weight] = $arrayWeight[1];
//  $arrayWeight[1] = 'weight' >= 0 && 'weight' <=40    a string

Comment: its for the option i added as you can see there are 5 options now, in the html  you can remove it if you don't need that, but the value in  your input must start with 0, since array starts with zero

Comment: i didnt get any changes when i upadated my code with urs

Comment: where to put it? is it in PHP page or in html

Comment: please see the updates. i have replace the single quote with magic quotes in the 'weight'=`weight` and i remove a comma at the last that might cause an error

Comment: i have checked it @bdalina but nothing changes except the url

Comment: at you php code try to var_dump the full query, and try to see also the headers sent, by inspecting the element, in the network tab.